# Run INSERT in sql for every ID selected with SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that selects a column(ID) and has multiple rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.ID FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `posts` AS ships ON users.ID = ships.post_author WHERE ships.post_author IS NULL
```

Now I want to INSERT into posts table for every ID and use the id in the post_author column

```
INSERT INTO `posts` (`ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`) VALUES (NULL, 'THE IDs from the select statement', DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 HOUR), NOW())
```

//Edit
I would like to do something more, how can I insert into one more table?
As 'post_id' I need the the autoincrement ID from the INSERT statement.
LAST_INSERT_ID() does not work I think.

```
INSERT INTO `postmeta` (`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`)
VALUES ('ID OF THE ABOVE INSERT', '_start_date', DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 HOUR));
```

Comment: How can I do that in a single query, insert a row into posts table for every row from  the select statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do using a single query using an insert select

```
INSERT INTO `posts` (`ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`) 

SELECT DISTINCT  null, users.ID , DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 HOUR), NOW()
FROM `users` 
LEFT JOIN `posts` AS ships ON users.ID = ships.post_author 
WHERE ships.post_author IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm.

Comment: Will do, but I edited the question, do you think it's possible to do that as well?

Comment: @Alex  select insert work on a single table  only  .so is not possible what asked in your updated  question  . anyway change the question after you have obtained  a correct answer is not fair ..

Comment: No worries, I will accept your answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
INSERT INTO `posts` (`ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`)
SELECT DISTINCT  NULL AS `ID`,
users.ID AS `post_author`,
NOW() - INTERVAL 7 HOUR AS `post_date`,
NOW() AS `post_date_gmt`
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN `posts` AS ships ON users.ID = ships.post_author
WHERE ships.post_author IS NULL
```

Comment: Does not work, I get lots of errors!